# Grails unit test resulting in null instance

Tags: unit-testing, grails, scaffolding

I am trying to get unit testing to work for scaffolding. There are a few changes that I made to the original scaffolding template to serve what I needed for my application. This is the code for the test:

```
void "Test that the show action returns the correct model"() {
    when:"A domain instance is passed to the show action"
        populateValidParams(params)
        def domainName = new DomainName(params)
        controller.show(domain.toString())

    then:"A model is populated containing the domain instance"
        model.domainNameInstance == domainName
}
```

This is the code for the show action, where I grab the domain instance from the database based on two values within the id, which is created by a toString method within the controller:

```
def show(String id){
    if (id!=null){
        def (term, college)=id.split('_')
        DomainName domainNameInstance
        respond domainNameInstance=DomainName.findByVal1AndVal2(val1, val2)
    }else{
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND)
    }
}
```

The issue that I am having is that when I run the test, the domainInstance is null within the test, whereas the domain is returning the right values. Would someone know what I need to change to make the domainInstance inside the test not null? For reference, I am using Grails 2.4.3 and the Scaffolding 2.1.2 plugin.

Answer (score 0):

In your unit test, you need to save the `DomainName` instance you are creating. Your `show` action is querying the database but you haven't persisted the test instance.

Comment: I tried that using controller.save(domainName), but I get an error stating that the CREATED property doesn't exist for the controller.

Comment: Sounds like you're missing an `import static org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.*`

Comment: That is included in my controller. When I test the save function, it passes. It's only the show and edit functions that are having this issue, and they have the exact same code within them. The first test for show tests to see if it returns a 404 if the instance is null, which it passes that test, so the import statement is not an issue.